# MVC 5 Authorize still allowing access after session expiry

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have a new MVC 5 project which follows the bare minimum OWIN example here:
http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux

I have then applied the [Authorize] attribute to all controllers except for my login controller. When I first start the website, I am required to log in and I cannot hit any other controllers until I do - great so far.

I have turned my session length down to 1 minute like so:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="1" />
</system.web>
```

Now when I log in, I wait 1 minute, then the application hits the following line:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session_End");
}
```

After this however, I can still navigate to any controller I want to. My session variables are all empty, but the system still thinks I'm an authorized user.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it so that when the session expires (after 1 minute), the user is required to log in again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application cookies are being managed by the Identity membership system. Search for the method **UseCookieAuthentication**. You must set the **ExpireTimeSpan** property so it will look something like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
     LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
     ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),

...
```

Comment: Thank you - this explains it. I have implemented your changes and it is working as expected now.